# Увеличить скорость выполнение кода python

Tags: python, оптимизация, машинное-обучение, numpy

Как увеличить скорость выполнения данного кода. X - двумерный np. array, x,y - одномерные np.array, k - int

```
def knn_predict_simple(X, y, x, k):
    distances = [(X[row], y[row], euclidean(x, X[row])) for row in range(len(X))]
    distances.sort(key=lambda i: i[2])


    votes = {}
    for i in range(k):
        answer = distances[i][1]
        if answer in votes:
            votes[answer] += 1
        else:
            votes[answer] = 1
    return [(int(k), v) for k, v in votes.items()]
```

**Пример вызова функции:**

```
    X = np.array([[1, 2, 1], [1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 1]])
    y = np.array([1, 0, 1, 1, 1])
    x = np.array([1, 2, 2])
    k = 2
    neighbors = knn_predict_simple(X, y, x, k)
```

**Update!
Уменьшил код, но он также не проходит по времени.**

```
def knn_predict_simple(X, y, x, k):
    distances = [(y[i], euclidean(x, X[i])) for i in range(len(X))]
    distances.sort(key=lambda i: i[1])
    answer = [distances[i][0] for i in range(k)]
    index, value = np.unique(answer, return_counts=True)
    return list(zip(index, value))
```

Comment: дайте хоть пример вызова функции) а то даже протестировать никак нельзя)

Comment: Добавил пример вызова

Comment: А вам для чего ускорить то нужно? Это учебное задание такое или у вас очень много данных и всё это тормозит?

Comment: Да, учебное. В тестирующей системе, на двух тестах валится по времени.

Comment: @james А, ну если учебное, то вам придётся подумать, как сделать все вычисления по возможности в векторном виде, а не в циклах. И, возможно, сделать мемоизацию, имитируя кэш. В тестах обычно продвинутые библиотеки использовать не дают.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как сказано в [ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1401828/3679682) на другой вопрос, можно воспользоваться [`numpy.linalg.norm`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html), а также поменять код функции:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean

X = np.array([[1, 2, 1], [1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 1]])
y = np.array([4, 0, 1, 3, 1])
x = np.array([1, 2, 2])
k = 2

def knn_predict_simple(X, y, x, k):
    distances = [(y[i], euclidean(x, X[i])) for i in range(len(X))]
    distances.sort(key=lambda i: i[1])
    answer = [distances[i][0] for i in range(k)]
    index, value = np.unique(answer, return_counts=True)
    return list(zip(index, value))

def knn_new(X, y, x, k):
    dist = np.linalg.norm(X-x, axis=1)
    idx_sort = dist.argsort()
    answer = y[idx_sort[:k]]
    index, value = np.unique(answer, return_counts=True)
    return list(zip(index, value))
```

Тестирование по времени старой версии:

```
%%time
neighbors = knn_predict_simple(X, y, x, k)
neighbors
>> CPU times: user 2.29 ms, sys: 200 µs, total: 2.49 ms
>> Wall time: 1.49 ms
>> [(3, 1), (4, 1)]
```

Тестирование по времени новой версии:

```
%%time
neighbors = knn_new(X, y, x, k)
neighbors
>> CPU times: user 201 µs, sys: 0 ns, total: 201 µs
>> Wall time: 168 µs
>> [(3, 1), (4, 1)]
```

Comment: Благодарю, ваше решение проходит)

Answer (score 3):

Вариантов ускорить код без особых усилий много. Навскидку:

1. Есть готовые библиотечные функции для вычисления евклидова расстояния, по идее они уже должны быть оптимизированы. Например: scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean
2. Можно попробовать использовать декоратор numpy.jit перед функциями, он часто бывает ускоряет математические вычисления в функциях, особенно если есть циклы.
3. Можно вынести вычисление квадрата разности двух чисел в отдельную функцию и использовать для этой функции декоратор functools.lru_cache

Comment: Использование scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean помогло пройти один тест по времени, но на последнем валится. Обновил код.

Comment: @james Возможно, в вашем случае, кстати, cdist подойдёт из того же подпакета SciPy. Она сразу матрицу расстояний считает. Чтобы в цикле не перебирать. Вообще посмотрите пакет scipy.spatial.distance там, возможно, есть прямо нужная функция для всей задачи.

Comment: @james, попробуйте использовать https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances.html

Comment: К сожалению sklearn пользоваться запрещенно